# Linux backup recommendation?

Tags: backup, clonezilla

I've read this excellent post: [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

...But I'm having trouble finding one that meets my criteria. Hopefully someone with some hands-on experience can save me the weeks of trying each package :)

This is what I'm looking for:

1. Scheduling so I can run a weekly backup
2. Backup must cover the ENTIRE system for a quick restore in a jam. Similar to Clonezilla.
3. Prefer bootable USB/CD to restore from

If anyone is familiar with Acronis in Windows, I'm looking for something like that. Set it to 1AM Friday mornings, and let it do its thing. If I hose my Ubuntu install, I pop in a USB stick, punch in my NAS address, and let it restore.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Everything you are asking for is covered quite well in the question you linked...

Comment: I've read this link (which I quoted), and can't find anything that meets my exact criteria. As stated, it's more reasonable for me to ask, then to try 20 backup tools.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu use deja dup as default here you have a guide.     [guide link](http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/)

if that dosent work in this discucion you have sevral tools to do backups .   [Backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Comment: Deja dup won't do a full system backup, no?

Comment: no , but if you read the other link you have many options . or use the tar command like ** tar -zvcfp /backups/fullbackup.tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc
--exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups **.  or use the dd  command ** dd if=sdx of=/directory/to/backup.iso ** the other option is to read the second link i left you in the first answer